# Get Mouse Coordinates from other class

Tags: c#, class

I have a class A and B, class A gets a point coordinates made by Mouse_Move event of class B, but returns 0 while I begin moving mouse in Panel. What is the problem, im confused seriously?:

```
        public class A
    {
        public A()
        {
        }
        private Point Point_;
        public Point MOUSEPOINT
        {
            get { return Point_; }
            set { this.Point_ = value; }
        }
    }
    public class B:A
    {
        public B(Panel panel)
        {
            panel.MouseMove += Panel_MouseMove;
        }

        private void Panel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MOUSEPOINT = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }
    }
```

Hope for your help

Comment: What "returns 0"?  The properties `X` and `Y` inside the event arguments?

Comment: MOUSEPOINT variable returns 0 in class A. Of course it has X and Y, it is a standard of MouseEventArgs. Moreover the point consists of these two coordinates... And one moment else. When i make a panel object in Form class and then set MouseMove event in it, set the class A, and get coordinates from e.Location, it works well. But when I do written in topic, it returns 0

Comment: If you've created an instance of class `A` then there is nothing to ever set the value of `MOUSEPOINT`.  It can only be set by events handled by instances of class `B`.  What have you actually created?